# HBase multiple Row filter range greater and less than possible?

Tags: hbase, rowfilter

I'm exploring HBase and trying to scan a range of rows in a certain range. For example, if my keys are just integers (less than 10 for this example), in trying this:

```
hbase(main):030:0> scan 'testtable', {FILTER => "RowFilter(<, 'binary:8)", FILTER => "RowFilter(>, 'binary:2')"}
```

Yet this results in the following, it seems to be not able to combine a "range" of rows? Is this possible?

ROW                                               COLUMN+CELL
 3                                                column=colfam1:q1, timestamp=1434692947170, value=33
 3                                                column=colfam1:q2, timestamp=1434692969969, value=33
 4                                                column=colfam1:q1, timestamp=1434692532607, value=4
 8                                                column=colfam1:q1, timestamp=1434692527505, value=4
 9                                                column=colfam1:q1, timestamp=1434692519223, value=9

Comment: Doh, this needs an "AND"..so it should be : scan 'testtable', {FILTER => "RowFilter(<, 'binary:8') AND (RowFilter(>, 'binary:2')"}

Answer (score 0):

Doh, this needs an "AND"..so it should be : scan 'testtable', {FILTER => "RowFilter(<, 'binary:8') AND (RowFilter(>, 'binary:2')"} –